# Bacon.when not matching streams as expected

Tags: javascript, frp, bacon.js

In experimenting with Bacon.js, I've come across the following unexpected behavior:

```
    var email = $("#email")
                            .asEventStream("keyup")
                            .map(function(event) {
                                return $(event.target).val();
                            })
                            .log();

    var validEmail = email.map(validateEmail).log();

    // submit.doAction('.preventDefault'); isn't working for some reason
    $('form').on('submit', function (event) { event.preventDefault() });

    var submit = $('form').asEventStream('submit');

    // postFormData is never called
    Bacon.when([email, validEmail, submit], postFormData);
```

Each of the streams emits values appropriately, but the join pattern is never matched.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gsjmdr4/)

Comment: Bacon.js omg this is getting out of hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never do anything with the result of `Bacon.when`, so lazy evaluation causes postFormData never to be called.

As a rule of thumb, something that causes side effects, like posting the data to server, should be done in an `onValue` handler. Combining the different EventStreams should be done using pure functions.

I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3gsjmdr4/1/) by adding a `.log` at the end.

Comment: OK - this makes sense. [The docs](https://github.com/baconjs/bacon.js/#join-patterns-as-a-chemical-machine) could do a better job of explaining what you just have. (There's no assignment of the result of `when` and the matching functions (i.e. `make_water`) would appear to have side effects.) You should consider submitting a PR!

Comment: This is one of the major pitfalls in Bacon.js that many people run into.

Comment: As a side note, you don't need `Bacon.when` for this sort of code, simpler `combine`, `combineWith` and `combineTemplate` would do.

Comment: If you want an example of form field handling with bacon, you can check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bFL4D/4/) from a presentation I gave at work about frp and bacon: http://ollimahlamaki.fi/baconjs-presentation/

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using `combineAsArray`. I'll definitely check out your presentation. Thanks for your feedback!